# How can I add button[type=submit] to React-ladda button component in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I'm trying to add `button[type=submit]` to React-ladda button.
There is no information regarding this in the React-ladda documentation.

Though, the Javascript Ladda documentation tells me to use `LaddaButton.bind( 'button[type=submit]' );`

I'm not able to figure out how to add this to the `<LaddaButton></LaddaButton>`
React component.

Comment: You mean you want to set your React LaddaButton's type=submit or you want to convert your button which type=submit to a React LaddaButton?

Comment: I meant to set the React LaddaButton's type=submit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To define your LaddaButton type as submit, you may just add the type property to LaddaButton

```
<LaddaButton
    loading={this.state.expLeft}
    onClick={() => this.toggle('expLeft')}
    data-color="green"
    data-style={EXPAND_LEFT}
    type="submit">
        Click
</LaddaButton>
```